# Transforming a JSON input subarray into a string sequential list output

Tags: json, jq

Here is my input:

```json
{
  "alias-name": "soufriere",
  "member-entry": {
    "alias-entry-name": [
      "21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7e",
      "21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7f"
    ]
  }
}
{
  "alias-name": "stromboli",
  "member-entry": {
    "alias-entry-name": [
      "21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:8e"
      "21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:9e"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to turn this into output

```
alicreate "soufriere","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7e;21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7f"
alicreate "stromboli","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:8e;21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:9e"
```

I tried this:

```bash
jq -r --arg quote "\"" ("alicreate " + $quote + ."alias-name" + $quote + "," + $quote + ."member-entry"."alias-entry-name"[] + $quote)'
```

but it gives a one by one line instead of a sequential.

```
alicreate "soufriere","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7e"
alicreate "soufriere","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7f"
alicreate "stromboli","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:8e"
alicreate "stromboli","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:9e"
```

Comment: Missing comma on line 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over an array produces its items. To instead join the items into a single string, use the [`join` filter](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#join). Also, inside strings you can use `\"` to generate quotes, and [string interpolation `\(…)`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation) to inject values.

```bash
jq -r '"alicreate \"\(."alias-name")\",\"\(
  ."member-entry"."alias-entry-name" | join(";")
)\""'
```

```
alicreate "soufriere","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7e;21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7f"
alicreate "stromboli","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:8e;21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:9e"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qW2LqbcMGZl)

Note that you might want to properly escape the values, rather than just enclosing them with double quotes, but which encoding to use highly depends on the use-case of your output.

Comment: right from man,`-r` is for raw output and `-R` for input

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `@csv` filter to handle quoting for us:

```bash
jq -r '
  [."alias-name", (."member-entry"."alias-entry-name" | join(";"))]
  | @csv
  | "alicreate " + .
'
```

```
alicreate "soufriere","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7e;21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:7f"
alicreate "stromboli","21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:8e;21:00:f4:e9:d4:50:56:9e"
```